# How to rerender Vue component after user joins or leaves presence channel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-echo

I would like to display new array of users after I push another one user. But all I see only one user... How to implement this task of showing all users in the array when they come and go?

```
export default { 
  data() {
    return {
       users:[],       
   }    
},   

mounted() {
 var presenceChannel = Echo.join('presenceChat')
   .here((users) => {
       this.users = users;     
       });                      
   })
   .joining((user) => {
       this.users.push(user);
   })
   .leaving((user) => {
       this.users.splice(this.users.indexOf(user), 1);
    })
```

Comment: *'But all I see only one user...'*. Where do you see that, as the output of your template or in console logging? It would help if you could include **that** code so we could see what you're seeing.

Comment: you should console log out the joining user as it may be a data object containing the user. it will also let you know if a user is really joining. Vue will always update if you push new items to an array. there is no reason to force it.